# How to get the filter class or viewset class through model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-rest-framework-filters

I want to find the corresponding filter class or viewset class only through Model.

The corresponding Model can be found by filter class or viewset class, but it cannot be reversed. I have a naming of these three, there is a rule, I guess it can be found through the string name of the filter class or viewset class, but it can not be achieved

```
class Manager(models.Model)
```

```
class ManagerFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Manager
        fields = {'name': ['exact', 'in', 'startswith']}
```

```
class ManagerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_class = ManagerFilter
```

I can only get the Model class, I want to get the corresponding filter class or viewset class according to this Model.

Comment: A model does not per se has one related `ModelViewSet`, in fact a model can have zero, one, or more related `ModelViewSet`.

Comment: @willemVanOnsem understand, but I have rules about the naming between them. Can I find the class by class name? For example, there is a method to input class name and then output class.